# A set of everything that exists - can it exist?

Tags: everything

I imagine this argument might have been made before but couldn't find it on the exchange.

The world / cosmos / universe can be define as "whatever exists". It is then tempting to think of it as a set, the set of everything that exists. But such as set would not be consistent with modern math and logic.

It would fall pray to Russel's paradox, since if such a set existed, it would include itself... Also, such a set would have no boundary, since nothing can exist outside of it, it would have no "outside". So the universe, defined as "whatever exists", is not a set in the mathematical sense of the word.

Assuming this is right, and correct me if it's not, I am struggling to figure out the implications. Does it imply that the world is by definition, an open set?

Another way to say it, perhaps, would be that any thought of "the whole" transcends human reason, or at least human logic. But this is a bit too theological for my taste.

Comment: An open set is still a set and you already claimed "It is then tempting to think of it as a set, but such as set would not be consistent with modern math and logic"...

Comment: A set of everything that exists would have to contain itself, but that's typically impossible (though you can define a set in a different way to avoid the paradox).

Comment: It is not at all tempting to think of the universe as a set. A set is a mathematical abstraction, the universe is not. ["Open set"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set) does not mean what you think it means, what you allude to is called [proper class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)).  But it is not even tempting to *model* the universe as a mere set or class, it has a lot more structure, and set/class/"whole" technicalities are moot in the modeling. Human reason can handle much richer concepts, like [categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)).

Comment: @Conifold Thanks, that's useful, including the "class" terminology and the point about internal structure being more interesting than issues of delimitation.

Comment: If some issue is more interesting than delimitation and cannot be reduced to it then how can such issue be resolved?…

Comment: @DoubleKnot One could try and understand processes, evolutions, complex relationships between objects...

Answer (score 1):

Your question leaves open a series of points for clarification:

- The Russell antinomy says that there is no set, which contains all
  sets which are not(!) element of itself.
  But you consider the set of
  all that exists. I do not see why this set is prohibited by the Russell
  antinomy.
- You state that the set of all that exists is not a set.
  But then you
  ask, whether this is an open set. If the set does not exist, it makes
  not sense to ask whether it is an open set.
- That a set has no boundary does not hinder it to exist: The set of
  points on a sphere has no boundary.
  But spheres exist.
- The concept of “the whole” is a problematic concept. According to
  Kant the concept of the world as a whole leads to some antinomies of
  pure reason.

Comment: Russel's paradox shows that if one assumes the existence of sets that contain themselves, then one ends up in contradiction. Therefore sets cannot logically contain themselves. A sphere still has an "outside": a point can be imagined, that is not on the sphere. Would you have a reference for Kant's point, which strikes me as similar to mine?

Comment: @Olivier Russell’s antinomy does not prohibit sets, which are members of themselves. On the other hand, one needs the axiom of foundation in addition to Zermelo-Fraenkel to exclude the existence of sets which are members of themselves. -
If you take the usual 2-dimensional sphere S as topological space, then S has no boundary. But if you speak about the outside of the sphere then you consider S as subspace of the 3-dimensional Euclidean space. “Outside” then means complement. - 
Concerning Kant’s “antinomies of pure reason” see Kant: Critique of Pure Reason, B448 ff.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. There are several interpretations of Russell's paradox. Mine is that it's a modus tollens demonstration of the impossibility of self-containing sets, as follows: IF one assumes that some sets can contain themselves, THEN a paradox logically follows, THEREFORE sets cannot logically contain themselves.

Comment: @Olivier Could you please show how Russell's antinomy excludes sets which are members of themselves. Thanks.

Comment: If one assumes that at least some sets can contain themselves, then (and only then) one can postulate the existence of a set of all sets not member of themselves. This leads to a logical contradiction: if this set is a member of itself, it must not be a member of itself and vice versa. Therefore our original assumption was false.

Comment: @Olivier Please explain the meaning of the "if ... then" in your first sentence; notably, what does mean "one can postulate"?

Comment: "If A then B" = "A => B"

Comment: Postulate:
suggest or assume the existence, fact, or truth of (something) as a basis for reasoning, discussion, or belief.
"his theory postulated a rotatory movement for hurricanes"

Comment: @Olivier5 I ask for an argument which implies the conclusion in your first sentence.

Comment: "A set of all sets not members of themselves" cannot exist if one rules out the existence of sets that are members of themselves. Because it would then mean "a set of all sets".

Answer (score 0):

Since every one of the absolutely many transfinite cardinals is of a set that is said to "exist," then in the usual set theories, we would rather say that there is a proper class of everything that exists. *A* = {*x* | E*x*} is a comprehension principle that surpasses the set level, then. (In category theory, sometimes they go on to things they call conglomerates and then some even more rarefied "collections" beyond those, so we would want "the conglomerate of all existents" or "the collection" of them, etc.)

But if we confine ourselves to the more strictly "physical" domain of discourse, then again we must "count" the things that there are, and assign to them a set or a class (or whatever). In a Lewisian multiverse, for example, the number of worlds is the powerset number of the Continuum number, not just the Continuum number. These worlds cannot house more objects than there are worlds or permutations of the objects would result in more alternative worlds; the powerset number of the Continuum number corresponds to a set; ergo... On the other hand, there are also set theories where the Continuum can be inflated to the size of a proper class, so if there were only Continuum-many worlds or objects in however many worlds (even if just one), yet this could be had to mean having more objects than there are sets in the first place, i.e. a proper class of physical objects.

Or one might assume that there are only finitely many things in whatever world, either *ante rem* or *in re*, and there would be then a finite set of all existents. Or one might think that there are only countably many physical existents; then there could be a proper set of them all. And so on and on.

There is an old saying, too, that says that God is not a part of something *X* of which the rest of the world(s) is (are) also a part. This can be adapted to a saying that there is no set housing God and the rest of whatever exists. Granted, these sayings involve also saying that God exists, but never mind that, we're just trying to see whether we can use a single image to comprehend all the referents of whatever names and similar terms we use. Perhaps, then, we could refine what we say and claim merely that the concept of a divine simplicity is incompatible with a single set encompassing all that exists (and if any set-like thing houses God, this will somehow come out to the divine simplicity housing itself!).

---

On the other hand, suppose just sets and assume that a set of all and only existents doesn't itself exist. Then at least one thing that exists will not be an element of the set of all other existents (or else this one existent would still be an element of the intended set). If something exists by being an element of the set of things that exist, then this entity would be existent and inexistent together, which we are not likely to credit with being the case. But notice then that we can ask about "the set of all existents," "the set of all other existents than *x*" (for some value of *x*), etc.

Comment: This flew high over my head.